# MacBook Pro Installation Fails to create "/" directory

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, macbook

Lately my MacBook Pro stopped working because of the newest Mac OS X update. I had to format my drive. I tried installing Windows 10, but this was no success. So now I try installing Ubuntu, but this doesn't work either. I have a fully non partitioned disk and I try to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 64-bit version. Every time it fails to create "/" on partition 2. I don't know what to do now and I really want to be able to use this laptop again!

Thanks in advance,

Ablos

Comment: Are you getting an error message, what does it do when you try to install? Are you using LVM, what is your partition layout?

Comment: Wich MacBook Pro version is it? You sure it supports 64-bit?

Comment: @M.Becerra I think it doesn't support 64-bit, just found out. Not 100% sure but how can I install a 32-bit version if that isn't supported for GPT?

Comment: Can you specify the generation, version, model or anything helpful about your MacBook?

Comment: @M.Becerra I don't really know what mac it is, where can I find it? I don't have the package anymore, but I think it is from 2011

Comment: Is there any way you could reinstall OSX?

Comment: @M.Becerra I don't think so...

Comment: @M.Becerra guess this laptop is dead